# Аналог конфигурации object_parallel_to_source для moc_ файлов

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

Нашел, по слухам, недокументированную, конфигурацию `qmake`, позволяющую размещать объектные файлы в отдельных папках в соответствии со структурой самого проекта.

```
CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source
```

Это нужно, когда вы держите несколько классов с одинаковыми именами в разных неймспейсах, чтобы иметь одинаковые именна *файлов* для этих классов в разных директориях (действительно, глупо каждый раз создавать еще и разные имена файлов).

Если это классы не унаследованны от `QObject` все работает прекрасно, однако в обратном случает `qmake` создает moc_ClassName (.cpp .h) файлы, для которых правило для объектных файлов не действует, то есть все кидается в одну директорию.

Допустим мы создали два класса `ActionDouble` в двух разных неймспейсах и папках:

```
namespace Concept002 {

class ActionDouble : public Action
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ActionDouble(QObject *parent = 0);

    ...
};

}
```

и

```
namespace Concept003 {

class ActionDouble : public Action
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ActionDouble(QObject *parent = 0);

    ...
signals:

public slots:
};

}
```

получаем предупреждения и ошибки:

> warning: overriding recipe for target 'moc_ActionDouble.cpp'
>
> warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'moc_ActionDouble.cpp'

и как следствие:

> error: undefined reference to `vtable for Concept002::ActionDouble'

---

Собственно, в этом и состоит вопрос, может кто знает флаг конфигурации `qmake` (или же другой способ разрешения вышеописанной проблемы - иметь несколько классов в разных папках и разных неймспейсах с одним и тем же именем, и унаследованных от `QObject`), позволящий генерировать moc_ файлы в разных папках в соотвествии со струкурой проекта. Или, например, может быть можно сформировать моки как `moc_Namespace_ClassName`?

Comment: Вообще не обязательно, чтобы moc-файл имел то же имя, что и соответствующий cpp. Можно назначить им любые случайные имена. Главное - чтобы те же имена попали в Makefile. Но вот как это сделать - черт его знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложения делю на статик либы(ей же присваивается неймспейс). В одной либе нет дублирующихся имен. Причем использую подпроекты и руками указываю диру сборки по умолчанию объявляю ./build/[TARGET_ARCH] TARGET_ARCH добавляю через mkspec или в IDE Проекты -> сборка -> qmake -> Доп. параметры.

```
isEmpty(TARGET_ARCH){
   TARGET_ARCH=x86
}
BASE_PATH=$$PWD/$$TARGET_ARCH
OBJECTSDIR = $$BASE_PATH/obj/$${MODULE_NAME}/$${BUILD_TYPE}
DESTDIR = $$BASE_PATH/lib
```

**Структура проекта**

```
Module1  
   Module (namespace Module1)
      ClassA.cpp  (Module1::ClassA)
   Test
      ClassA.cpp (тут unit test Fixture|Mocks)
Module2  
   Module (namespace Module2)
      ClassA.cpp (Module2::ClassA)
   Test
      ClassA.cpp (тут unit test Fixture|Mocks)
```

Так заборол дублирующиеся имена объектников.